# 2019 Developer Survey

Tags: discussion

The Stack Overflow 2019 developer survey is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/dev-survey/start?utm_medium=so-blog&utm_source=so-owned&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2019) !

Obviously, as every year, the technologies and languages proposed do not include Salesforce.

Will the Salesforce Stack Exchange community be able to show that we are there and that we love what we do? :)

Comment: Ah it  finally works! Errored out every time I tried to start the survey yesterday.

Comment: Yes it works ! I just had to check "Other" each time a technology or language was proposed...

Comment: Put in my answers to it so did mention Salesforce, Apex and VF as well as the inevitable JS.